# Ignore "The" when sorting a View in Drupal

Tags: drupal, sorting, drupal-6, drupal-views

How can I ignore "The" when the user sorts a view in a Drupal site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the [Views Natural Sort Module](http://drupal.org/project/views_natural_sort) ?

*taken from module page linked above..*

> Provides a views filter that sorts
>   titles by a more natural manner by
>   ignoring articles like "The" and "A."