# How to sort in SQL, ignoring articles ('the", "a', "an" etc)

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting, switch-statement, trim

This comes up a lot, and I can see it's come up on StackOverflow for [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848641/ignoring-a-and-the-when-sorting-with-xslt), [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402915/sort-an-array-in-ruby-ignoring-articles-the-a-an) and [Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189092/ignore-the-when-sorting-a-view-in-drupal) but I don't see it specifically for SQL.

So the question is, how do you sort titles correctly when they begin with "The", "A", or "An"?

One way is simply to TRIM() those strings:

```
ORDER BY TRIM( 
  LEADING 'a ' FROM 
  TRIM( 
    LEADING 'an ' FROM 
    TRIM( 
      LEADING 'the ' FROM LOWER( title ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )
```

which was [suggested on AskMeFi](http://ask.metafilter.com/52434/How-to-get-mySQL-to-ignore-A-An-and-The-when-presenting-alphabetized-book-titles) a while back (does it need that `LOWER()` function?).

I know I've also seen some kind of Case/Switch implementation of this but it's a little hard to Google for.

Obviously there are a number of possible solutions. What would be good is SQL gurus weighing in on which have performance implications.

Comment: Agree with a commenter on one of the linked SO questions: the rules can turn out more complicated than it seems. Your particular suggestion, for instance, would probably fail to sort the following list correctly: `The A Test`, `The B Test`, `The C Test`.

Answer (score 7):

One approach I've seen was to have two columns - one for display and the other for sorting:

```
description  |  sort_desc
----------------------------
The the      | the, The
A test         | test, A
I, Robot      | i, Robot
```

I haven't done any real world testing, but this has the benefit of being able to use an index and doesn't require string manipulation every time you want to order by the description.  Unless your database supports materialized views (which MySQL doesn't), implementing the logic as a computed column in a view wouldn't provide any benefit because you can't index the computed column.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using this for years, but can't remember where I found it:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1) IN ('a', 'an', 'the') 
    THEN CONCAT( SUBSTRING( Title, INSTR(Title, ' ') + 1 ), ', ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1) ) 
    ELSE Title 
    END AS TitleSort,
Title AS OriginalTitle 
FROM yourtable 
ORDER BY TitleSort
```

Yielding:

```
TitleSort                  | OriginalTitle
------------------------------------------------------
All About Everything       | All About Everything
Beginning Of The End, The  | The Beginning Of The End
Interesting Story, An      | An Interesting Story
Very Long Story, A         | A Very Long Story
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change a couple of function names and syntax bits to make it PostgreSQL friendly for my purposes, but this is exactly what I was looking for:  

`CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(LOWER(Title), ' ', 1) IN ('a', 'an', 'the') THEN SUBSTR(Title, POSITION(Title, ' ') + 1) || ', ' || SPLIT_PART(Title, ' ', 1)) ELSE Title END AS TitleSort ...`

Answer (score 3):

For Postgres specifically, you can use regexp_replace to do the work for you:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE book (name VARCHAR NOT NULL) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('The Restaurant at the End of the Universe');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('Life, the Universe and Everything');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('Mostly Harmless');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('A book by Douglas Adams');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('Another book by Douglas Adams');
INSERT INTO book (name) VALUES ('An omnibus of books by Douglas Adams');

SELECT name FROM book ORDER BY name;
SELECT name, regexp_replace(lower(name), '^(an?|the) (.*)$', '\2, \1') FROM book ORDER BY 2;
SELECT name FROM book ORDER BY regexp_replace(lower(name), '^(an?|the) (.*)$', '\2, \1');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for SQL Server: you use LTRIM within CASE statements. No LOWER function is needed because selections are not case sensitive by default. However, if you want to ignore articles then I would suggest you use a noise word dictionary and set up a full text indexing catalog. I am unsure if other implementations are SQL support this.

Comment: Case sensitivity is dependent on collation.  Full Text Search (FTS) is available on MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server... Dunno what PostgreSQL's is but I'm sure it has native functionality.  And there are 3rd party FTS like sphinx...

Comment: "you use LTRIM within CASE statements" -- does this mean you do the equivalent of "if it starts with 'the ', trim it"? I was wondering if that would slow the process down, as opposed to a blanket TRIM() which might be failing most of the time.

Comment: LTRIM gets rid of leading spaces

Answer (score -1):

`LOWER` is needed.  While `SELECT` is not case-sensitive, `ORDER BY` is.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

ORDER BY 
replace(replace(replace(YOURCOLUMN,'THE',''),'a\'',''),'an','')

Not tested!

Comment: Surprised no one has explained the problem with this. When sorting, you want to replace LEADING articles, while this will replace ALL articles.